# Codeigniter form-validation is always returning false

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get form values and passing it in my model to store in the database. Whenever I end up submitting the form, I always get the values as NULL.

form.php

```
   <form action="http://localhost/hbp/review/submit/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
        <!--        <input type="text" name="title">-->
        <?php echo form_input(['id' => 'title', 'name' => 'title', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your review title']); ?>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Review</label>
        <!--        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="message"></textarea>-->
        <?php echo form_textarea(['id' => 'message', 'name' => 'message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your review title', 'rows' => '10', 'cols' => '100']); ?>
    </div>
    <button name="submit">Hello</button>
</form>
```

I have tried using both `form_input()` and simple HTML syntax for rendering form fields. None of them worked.

controller.php

```
    if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
        $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
        $name = $userProfile['name'];
        $email = $userProfile['email'];
        $picture = $userProfile['picture'];


        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message', 'required');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            echo "error in your form ";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('review_error', 'Please fill all the fields!');
            $this->load->view('pages/review');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('review_success', 'Thank you for you ');
            $this->review_model->set_review($name, $email, $picture);
            redirect(base_url() . 'review/');
        }
        echo "just dies";
```

model.php

```
class Review_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function set_review($google_name, $google_email, $google_image)
    {
        $data = array('review_title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'review_content' => $this->input->post('message'),
            'email' => $google_email,
            'name' => $google_name,
            'image_url' => $google_image);
        return $this->db->insert('reviews', $data);
    }

    public function get_review(){
        $query = $this->db->get('reviews');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

I keep getting the `review_title` can't be NULL.

Comment: `$this->form_validation->run() == TRUE` means no error. I think your are interpreting this wrong

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, I was trying out a desperate attempt to get form data somehow, i have edited the question.Please have a look @DanishAli

Comment: Check form data of both input fields with `print_r($this->input->post())` before `if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)`.

Comment: I'll try it out, just a sec.

Comment: Hey @DanishAli I just printed the data, I am getting the form field data. Now i am totally lost as to how it's causing a FormValidation error

Comment: Check the error message in the `if()` statement `<?php echo form_error('title'); ?>` and `<?php echo form_error('message'); ?>`

Comment: I tried that, no output.

Comment: Is `if()` stamement executing here?

Comment: You mean in the controller? Both the `if`'s are executing. If you don't mind could you look at this question of mine here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847575/how-to-retain-form-submitted-data-through-multiple-redirects