# How to retain form submitted data through multiple redirects?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

EDIT - I tried storing data inside session values and pass it as parameters for the model to process, but that didn't work either.

I have an HTML form to get user reviews. User can leave a review after logging into his Google Account. I am using the Google 0Auth 2.0 API for this. So when you click submit on the form, you're redirected to Google Authentication page where you can choose which account you'd like to use.

However if you click on "Add another account" and put in the credentials, the data that I got through my original `User Review Form` which is `title of review` and `review content` is "unset". I know this because the final query for the database that inserts the data obtained from the Google login as well as the `Review Form` outputs `"review_title" value can't be null`. I know it's very confusing but trust me this is the best I can explain it.

> Controller.php

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Googlelogin extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/src/Google_Client.php';
        require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php';
    }

    public function index()
    {
//      $this->load->view('pages/review');
    }

    public function login()
    {

        $clientId = 'dddd.googleusercontent.com'; //Google client ID
        $clientSecret = 'dddd-ddd'; //Google client secret
        $redirectURL = base_url() . 'googlelogin/login';

        //https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

        //Call Google API
        $gClient = new Google_Client();
        $gClient->setApplicationName('Login');
        $gClient->setClientId($clientId);
        $gClient->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
        $gClient->setRedirectUri($redirectURL);
        $google_oauthV2 = new Google_Oauth2Service($gClient);

        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $gClient->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
            header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirectURL, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }

        if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
            $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        }

        if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
            $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
//          print_r($userProfile);
            $name = $userProfile['name'];
            $email = $userProfile['email'];
            $picture = $userProfile['picture'];


            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'message');

            $title = $this->input->post('title');
            $message = $this->input->post('message');
            // MY SESSION SOLUTION 
            $this->session->set_userdata($array);

            $session_title = $this->session->userdata('title');
            $session_message = $this->session->userdata('message');

            print_r($this->input->post());
            if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
                echo "error in your form ";
                $this->session->set_flashdata('review_error', 'Please fill all the fields!');
                $this->load->view('pages/review');
//              redirect(base_url().'review/');
            } else {
                echo $title, $message;
                $this->session->set_flashdata('review_success', 'Thank you for you ');
                $this->review_model->set_review($name, $email, $picture, $session_title , $session_message);
                redirect(base_url() . 'review/');
            }
//          echo "just dies";
            die;
        } else {
            $url = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
            header("Location: $url");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the `login` method. Inside the `FormValidation` condition.

> Model.php

```
class Review_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function set_review($google_name, $google_email, $google_image, $title, $message)
    {
        $data = array('review_title' => $title,
            'review_content' => $message,
            'email' => $google_email,
            'name' => $google_name,
            'image_url' => $google_image);
        return $this->db->insert('reviews', $data);
    }

    public function get_review(){
        $query = $this->db->get('reviews');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

The models is giving the actual output i.e. `"review_title" cannot be NULL`.

Here's the form if anyone is interested.

> Form.php

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>review/submit/" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>'
           value='<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
<!--        <input type="text" name="title">-->
        <?php echo form_input(['name' => 'title', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your review title']); ?>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Review</label>
<!--        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="message"></textarea>-->
        <?php echo form_textarea(['name' => 'message', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter your review title', 'rows' => '10', 'cols' => '100']); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_submit(['name' => 'submit', 'value' => 'submit']) ?>
</form>
```

Comment: you MUST change your details on Google itself

Comment: I did, i deleted the keys entirely, got myself a fresh pair. I was using those keys to develop on localhost, so hopefully no threat to my production. Thank you so much for your guys's input.

Comment: :-) good, just thought I'd mention it again. Sadly I don't know the answer to your problem though

Comment: _“EDIT - I tried storing data inside session values and pass it as parameters for the model to process, but that didn't work either.”_ - what do you even mean by _“either”_ here, how would you expect this to work _without_ sessions in the first place? HTTP is _stateless_, so if you redirect around, you need to store any data you want to retain somewhere before you do so.

Comment: I didn't occur to me that Google login was causing redirects, so I was simply trying to pass along the form data without saving it into session. Let me paste the code for the `session` solution I am using. I pasted the code. check it out if you want.

Comment: The way you are storing values in session is wrong. `$array` is undefined here. Do like this
`$the_session = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
$this->session->set_userdata($the_session);`

Comment: hey @DanishAli thank you for coming, I tried your solution, I till get the `"review_title" cannot be null`.

Comment: After assigning the values to session check it first for confirmation and then use.

Comment: To check the session I moved the code block inside another `if statement`.  Something like this, `if ($this->session->userdata('title') and $this->session->userdata('message') != NULL) { // do stuff here}else{ //echo "error happened"; }` so far I am getting  "error happened".

Comment: Try this `if ($this->session->userdata('title') && $this->session->userdata('message'))`